# OCR library for a Mobotix IP Camera

Tags: java, c++, ocr, tesseract, ip-camera

I'm starting a new project for school and I was wondering whether there are any resources available. I've dabbled bit in some open source OCR projects, finding Tesseract to be one of the more accurate one(but still somewhat messy). Does anyone have an idea where I could start or if they can push me in the right direction with Tesseract or any other libraries/examples.

The camera is positioned onto a container with a serial number. That serial number (characters and numbers, bold white on different colors) needs to be recognized through a picture (screenshot of a live-feed stream) and that serial number is then looked up on the database to get the information that's required. I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

The language is preferably in Java/C++ as I only really have experience with those two programming languages and it would make it easier for me to get starting if I can put either one of those two languages to use.

Answer (score 0):

> The camera is positioned onto a container with a serial number.

I would presume that this means that the image you will be working with will always have the same dimensions, more or less. If not, you might have to manipulate the image so that the area covering the serial does not vary much between images.

> The camera is positioned onto a container with a serial number. That
>   serial number (characters and numbers, bold white on different colors)

Are you doing any pre processing on the image? Like for instance take any non white pixel and turn it black? That would make your OCR not dependant on image colour, thus increasing its flexibility.

Cropping the image to send to the OCR so that it includes only the numbers you want to decode should also improve the functionality of the OCR.

If that still doesn't work for you, you could try and train your Tesseract network as shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).